# If this gets out... / If it gets out

Tags: word-choice

> If **this** gets out, they will be fined.
>
> If **it** gets out, they will be fined.

What's the difference between them? I suppose that "this" could be "this information", but "it" - "this document". Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It" is singular, and always refers to something previously mentioned. So, consider what comes before this statement. Is there a singular thing - a fact, or a story, or an event - that you are referring to?

"This" is also singular, but it can be used to collect things that are not already collected - for example, you could highlight a number of different items and say "all this".

So, if you have previously spoken about various different details that have not been referred to by a single collective term, then "this" might be more appropriate.

Examples:

> This **story** is shocking. If **it** gets out, there'll be trouble.

In this example, 'it' refers back to the 'story', which is singular, even though it may contain many different details.

> I've heard what has been happening. If this gets out, there'll be trouble.

Here, there is only reference to 'what has been happening', which could be lots of different things over a period of time. Because there is no collective term, 'this' seems appropriate.